# Is it possible to assign a dupe to already closed question?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

Is there a way to assign a dupe to a question that is already closed for a non-dupe reason?

For example, the question was closed as "unclear/need details" but I happen to believe that I actually understood what OP was asking about and found an appropriate dupe target.

I did post the link in comments.  Was it all I could do?

Comment: Yes, that's all you can do.

Comment: You can reopen and then dupe close the question. It's easier when you have dupe hammer privileges, though.

Comment: Does the would-be dupe add anything to the corpus of the would-be target that would make it easier to find? If the answer is no, then don't bother.

Comment: Somewhat related [Why can't we change our close-vote reason?](/q/262657/15497888)

Answer (score 6):

It's usually not worth the time to re-open a question and vote to close as a dupe.  You have to get two more people to agree with you that the dupe closure is better than the normal closure, and then unless you have a gold badge, you have to get one more person to agree with you that the question is a dupe.

Leaving a comment is probably the best you can do.

Comment: Never thought that "reopen" was a good idea.

Comment: Well you can't close a closed question; what else was there to do besides reopen and close as dupe @PM77-1?

Comment: As I clearly did not know "what else was there" I posted my question for that exact reason.

Comment: @PM77-1: Yes, that was my answer.  I didn't assume you knew that.  Sorry if what I said came across that way.